# Unable to have the correct values returned with the SUM(CASE WHEN) query

Tags: sum, case, transpose

I wrote the query below to try and get the total values per crime(minor_category) returned into columns from the london_crime database, but the values that are being returned are clearly incorrect when compared to the overall stats for those types of crimes in the dataset. What am I doing wrong?

SELECT
borough,
SUM(CASE WHEN minor_category = 'Rape' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Rape_Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN minor_category = 'Criminal Damage to Motor Vehicle' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Criminal_Damage_Total
FROM
`bigquery-public-data.london_crime.crime_by_lsoa`
GROUP BY
borough;

For example, the no of incidents / total values of Criminal Damage to Motor Vehicle for the Brent borough is 8433. In the table, from the query I created, it shows up as a 0 value. Essentially, I have values in a row format that I need to transpose to multiple columns, but obviously I am ddoing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

[Crime type per Borough](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTke6.png)

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery or Any SQL is case-sensitive. Use the below query. It should be `To` instead of `to`

```
SELECT borough, 
SUM(CASE WHEN minor_category = 'Rape' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Rape_Total,
SUM(CASE WHEN minor_category = 'Criminal Damage To Motor Vehicle' THEN value ELSE 0 END) AS Criminal_Damage_Total
FROM bigquery-public-data.london_crime.crime_by_lsoa 
GROUP BY borough;
```

If you find answer useful, please accept and upvote the answer

[image]